# Mount UFS filesystem

Tags: 11.10, mount, nas

How do I mount a partition with UFS filesystem (FreeNAS) in Ubuntu 11.10?

I'm a total Ubuntu newbie and just switched from FreeNAS.

There should be ll the info I need I guess, but if anyone would help me get going i'll by glad =)
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/mount.8.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Mounting UFS file systems in Ubuntu should be straight forward. Follow these simple steps to make sure that your are mounting your FreeNAS disks properly in Ubuntu:

Load the UFS module (or make sure its loaded)

```
sudo modprobe ufs
```

Make a directory where to mount the files on

```
mkdir ~/ufs_mount
```

To find out which device holds your UFS file system use the command `fdisk -l`, note which device you intend to mount.

Mount the file system to the directory your previously created

```
sudo mount -r -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdb1 /home/<your_username>/ufs_mount
```

(where: `sdb1` is the UFS partition you want to mount and `<your_username>` is the your current username where the intended mounting point was created previously.

Comment: Thank you! I think I've missed a step before though, as in "adding" the disk to the system somehow? Because the command seems to mount a partion, and I haven't yet mounted the disk.`code`mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: what does `sudo fdisk -l` output (add it to your question by pressing the edit button)

Comment: The command did not output anything :/

Comment: try with `sudo`, I fixed the request in the comment (without sudo does not output anything)

Comment: `cat /proc/partitions` will also do, again add that to the question it self instead of as a comment here

Comment: It worked with another UFS disk I have! Now I have to figure out how to save the other one. Thank you Bruno Pereira for your help!

Comment: Will this auto-mount the drive on any reboots?